# open a menu from Image View

Tags: java, android, menu, imageview

I have problem to set a menu.
I want to open a menu from an `ImageView`, because I want to use a specific image on the tool bar.
I can't found any tutorials

[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater =getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.days, menu);


    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create menu something like this?

[image: Basic Menu Android]
[image: Basic Menu Android]

Menu xml code: menu/days.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_love"
        android:title="Love"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_favorite_border_white_48"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_more"
        android:title="More"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_add_white_48"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/sub_item_1"
                android:title="Sub Item 1"
                app:showAsAction="withText"
                />

            <item android:id="@+id/sub_item_2"
                android:title="Sub Item 2"
                app:showAsAction="withText"
                />

            <item android:id="@+id/sub_item_3"
                android:title="Sub Item 3"
                app:showAsAction="withText"
                />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Full source code: https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/basic-menu-android

Hope it will help you. Thanks!

Comment: but its with adding a item to original actionbar i want to make it from toolbar and imageview